# Error while trying to load an image with async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I tried to implement an image async task I got from here:

http://schimpf.es/asynctask-for-image-download/

I then tried to execute it in my code like this:

```
ImageView im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
ImageDownloadTask imageD = new ImageDownloadTask(im1);
imageD.execute(e.mediumLabel);
```

I then got this error:

```
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.ImageDownloadTask.doInBackground(ImageDownloadTask.java:42)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.ImageDownloadTask.doInBackground(ImageDownloadTask.java:1)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-19 15:22:23.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18376):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call your logging `Log.e` you are not passing in valid strings, one of them is null. See `ImageDownloadTask line 42`

Comment: That made it run, but the image never showed up and I got this error:

06-19 16:57:05.598: E/libEGL(28922): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)